# Error when connecting to DB2 database from .Net web application via SSL Certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, db2

In my .Net web application when connecting to DB2 database via SSL Certificate(ODBC connection). I got following error:

```
Error:ERROR [08001] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "SSL".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "".  Communication function detecting the error: "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".  Protocol specific error code(s): "410", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

**My connection string:**

```
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=***;HOSTNAME=***.COM;Port=442;
UID=****;Security=SSL;Authentication=certificate;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
SSLClientLabel=*****;
Ssl_client_keystoredb=C:\Test\samples\GSK8\pr_test.kdb;
Ssl_client_keystash=C:\Test\samples\GSK8\pr_test.sth;
```

Comment: I would start by going to Control Panel : Admin Tools : Data Sources (ODBC) and see if driver is listed for database.

Comment: It is very unlikely that your database is configured to use the reserved port 442. Work with your DBA to find out what the database manager's ssl_svcename is set to.

Comment: However when i modify my connection string to have username and password instead of KDB file with the same port = 442, its working...

Comment: The gsk protocol error code 410 means the SSL configuration is incorrect.  Edit your question to supply more facts (1) how you put the Db2-server public key into the key database and the format etc.  (2) what operating-system the Db2-server runs on (iSeries, Z/OS, Linux/Unix/Windows .  (3) Which Db2-client software version is installed on the machine , and (4) whether you have a GSK installed.

Comment: What i did so far:...

1.Installed gsk version 8(gsk8 got installed automatically when i installed Rational Developer for Z)
2.Created a key database/key store on my system, which created .kdb file
3. Added signing certs to your key database/key store (which is .kdb file)
4. Installed and Imported the process ID certificate(.p12) to .kdb file
5. I Listed the key database to make sure all the needed certificates are there
6. I Set the process ID certificate as default

Comment: Working connection string(if i use username and password) which is working:
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=DSN12;Server=***;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;

Modified connection string(to use SSL) which is NOT working:
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=DSN12;HOSTNAME=***.**.COM;Port=442;
UID=****;Security=SSL;Authentication=certificate;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
SSLClientLabel=***;
Ssl_client_keystoredb=C:\Test\samples\pr_test.kdb;
Ssl_client_keystash=C:\Test\samples\pr_test.sth;

DB2 Server runs in Z/OS
I am using DB2 data server client version: 10.5

Comment: Please edit your question to add new facts. Do not add new facts in comments.
(1) version of Db2-server on Z/OS.
(2) What do you mean by "process id certificate" ?
(3) Double check SSL-port-number for the Db2-for-Z/OS.
(4) For unencrypted connections, are you going via Db2-connect?
(5) post the messages in db2diag.log on client when SSL connection fails. Set DIAGLEVEL 4 if possible.
(6) On the client side, if you are attempting a direct connect (i.e. not going via Db2-connect )you need a relevant license.

Comment: This issue got resolved now. I gave the wrong Port number. Thanks ALL for your support.